# Fill property in Web service .net

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, properties, fill

I'm quite new to Web Services.
I have web service, here's link http://pastebin.com/hnNH84KG, and own XML data file (generated by XSD schema).

I need to fill properties in web service, but i cant find any method.
This web service contain only generated properties.
I tried to parse my XMl and fill every single property, but, i think it's not the best way.
Is there any way to fill properties without calling and writing everyone?

Comment: Generate a service reference to that WSDL, then you can access the service using the `...ServiceClient` from code.

Comment: I have ws in WSDL representation imported in my project, but, still i can't find/use method to work with input XML file.

Comment: I think you don't understand my comment, but if so, then please say so. I'm not talking about adding the WSDL to your project. See [MSDN: How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I expressed badly.
I already have imported ws in my project as ServiceReference.

Comment: Then read the paragraph "Using the WCF Client" in [Accessing Services Using a WCF Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)...